# Aligning grouped text across multiple lines

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am trying to create a CV with a list of publications and am relatively new to latex formatting. I would like to have the publication number and then equally aligned, the authors, name and conference. So in the picture here, I would like the apple and AGDAL to be algined with TEST.
[image]

Here is what I currently have:

```
\newcommand*{\publication}[4]{%
    \honordatestyle{#4} & 
      {#2} \\&&
        {#1} \\&&
     {#3} && 
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the publication entries using a list:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\publication}[3]{%
% \publication{<num>}{<author(s)>}{<institution(s)>}
  \begin{itemize}[nosep]
    \item[{[#1]}] #2 \par #3
  \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}

\publication{10}{Some author}{Some institution}

\publication{3}{Another author}{Another institution}

\publication{18}{Final set of authors}{Yet another institution}

\end{document}
```

List numbering can be automated, and made possibly to cross-reference, if needed.